# get Pano id from url

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want get pano Id from url for this I am getting value between of this " !1s and !2e" and its working if I am adding that url its working correctly my url is that :-

https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Imeco/@51.5977674,4.7798587,3a,75y,20h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1sJ2eABozF-5QAAAQvOdWj5g!2e0!3e2!6s%2F%2Fgeo3.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DJ2eABozF-5QAAAQvOdWj5g%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dsearch.TACTILE.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D129%26h%3D106%26yaw%3D20.186041%26pitch%3D0!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x47c69f9b58df51db:0xb0bfd2c35e669225!8m2!3d51.5977691!4d4.779878!6m1!1e1

but when I using that url :-

https://www.google.nl/maps/uv?hl=nl&pb=!1s0x47c69f9b58df51db:0xb0bfd2c35e669225!2m5!2m2!1i80!2i80!3m1!2i100!3m1!7e115!4s/maps/place/imeco/@51.5977674,4.7798586,3a,75y,20.19h,90t/data%3D*213m4*211e1*213m2*211sJ2eABozF-5QAAAQvOdWj5g*212e0*214m2*213m1*211s0x0:0xb0bfd2c35e669225!5simeco+-+Google+zoeken&imagekey=!1e2!2sJ2eABozF-5QAAAQvOdWj5g&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLvoCJ-4jNAhXHJsAKHdgOAlIQoB8IfTAK

its not working correctly because in this url I didn't find this keyword !1s and !2e in this case how I can find Pano id

Answer (score 0):

When you run the url through decodeURIComponent(), you notice that in the first url the panoid equals "J2eABozF-5QAAAQvOdWj5g", the string between "panoid=" and the next "&".

In the second url, you see that string twice again, once between "*211s" and "*212e0" and again between "&imagekey=!1e2!2s" and "&sa=".
I'm not that familiar with google maps, but if the second url keeps this exact format for all references, i'd try the second occurence between "&imagekeyXXXXXXX" and "&sa=".

Do have a look at the documentation. I wouldn't be surprised if google has standard methods to extract or otherwise get this data. Can't imagine you need to chop up the url to get these.